# Parallel Tests With Selenium Visual

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I am trying the parallel tests using selenium. What I am doing is copying and pasting the test class as many times as I want my test to be executed. Then I just press run all the tests and it works fine, but I want to know if I can run just one method in one class many times instead of copying and posting it.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not sure it's selenium specific feature (if we are not talking about Selenium Grid). What testing framework you are using? (NUnit, MSUnit?)

Comment: @SergeyProsin NUnit

Comment: Then ensure you use 3.7+ version and use Parallelizable attribute. See my answer for details.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is a data driven test? See [NUnit docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData). Basically you have a single script that is fed different sets of data. Is that what you are wanting? Each set of data is a different run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution basically depends on the testing framework you are using. NUnit supports parallel test execution starting from 3.7 version. The example demonstrating the idea is below

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Dummy
    {
        static TestCaseData Case(int i)
            => new TestCaseData(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).SetName($"Case {i}");

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases()
            => Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Case);

        [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases)), Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
        public void ItShouldSleep(TimeSpan t)
            => Thread.Sleep(t);


        static TestCaseData Case2(int i)
            => new TestCaseData(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).SetName($"Case2 {i}");

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases2()
            => Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Case2);

        [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases2)), Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
        public void ItShouldSleep2(TimeSpan t)
            => Thread.Sleep(t);
    }

    [TestFixture()]
    public class Dummy2
    {
        static TestCaseData Case(int i)
            => new TestCaseData(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).SetName($"Case {i}");

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases()
            => Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Case);

        [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases)), Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
        public void ItShouldSleep(TimeSpan t)
            => Thread.Sleep(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please explain me the last part of your code what does the both classes Dummy and Dummy2 do i didn't get them well and thanks

Comment: ItShouldSleep is the method we want to test, Cases is the source for test cases data, ItShouldSleep will be executed as many types as number of elements returned by Cases method, Case method is a helper, it should return data for test case based on it's index

Comment: See TestCaseSource attribute documentation for details. It is a part on NUnit framework.

Comment: Thanks for your information and what about the main function he does not go there ?

Comment: I deleted it to not confuse anyone.

Comment: If my answer solves the problem you have don't hesitate to mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177741/discussion-between-aouadi-slim-and-sergey-prosin).

Comment: am kinda stuck and didn't know what to do can u help me please ?

Comment: What exact issues you are facing? Did you tried my code sample?

Comment: join me in chat room it's better

Comment: I can't connect to chat, let's continue here or you could update the question if there is a lot to say

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey Prosin update of question , I used your sample of code to adapt it on mine but the problem is that it opens 5 instances of Chrome but it only works on only one instance instead of the 5 of them simultaniously

```
   [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases)), Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
        public void ItShouldSleep(TimeSpan t)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
            Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\slaouadi\source\repos\UnitTestProject1", options);
            string baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("IT WORKED FINE");

        }
```

Comment: Hi, I see Driver variable is declared outside of the method. In this case, every new driver value overrides the previous ones. Just set var before Driver used the first time.

Comment: You need to make Driver method specific.